# Hiding cell in Jupyter

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I've been trying to hide the input of a code cell in Jupyter by adding the tag `hide-input` to it. However, it doesn't seem to be working. What is the most up to date way of doing it?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to hide any input code cell, I would recommend you to use:

```
# Specific code we want to hide:
# ==============================
# @hidden
from IPython.display import HTML
password="xxxxx"
# ==============================

# Necessary script to hide the cell:
# ==============================
HTML('''<script>
  code_show=true; 
  function code_toggle() {
    if (code_show){
        $('.cm-comment:contains(@hidden)').closest('div.input').hide();
    } else {
        $('.cm-comment:contains(@hidden)').closest('div.input').show();
    }
    code_show = !code_show
  } 
  $( document ).ready(code_toggle);
</script>
To show the code hidden: click <a href="javascript:code_toggle()">here</a>.''')
# ==============================
```

This solution was originally provided by [Damian Kao](https://blog.nextgenetics.net/?e=102). And works perfectly.

It also adds the toggle-on/off functionality: When you run this cell, the code will be hidden by default. But you can show it by clicking on the link.

Answer (score 0):

According to the latest documentation youi can use the:
`{toggle}`
directive to hide/un-hide elements in a Jupyter Notebooks, as noted in [1](https://jupyterbook.org/interactive/hiding.html).

The example given is:

```
:show:
Some hidden toggle content!

![](../images/cool.jpg)
```

Comment: But that's only for a markdown cell, right?

Comment: This has also been driving me bananas. I'm trying to get my notebook in NBviewer with hidden code cells. I can hide them locally, but when I send the nb to github they show up again. I have tried adding the tag "hide-input" using the tag and the metadata editors. No love. I feel like there must be a solution that I am missing.