# Jupyter Tags - remove-cell does nothing

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

[image: Code Cell and Tags]

In a Jupyter notebook I am trying to hide the code such that when I print to a pdf or some other format the code will not display.

To do this I have added the tags suggested [here](https://jupyterbook.org/en/stable/interactive/hiding.html), as shown in the screenshot.  I have also tried using hide-cell, hide-input, hide-output, etc.

Then when I print to PDF the code cell still shows.

I have also tried using both of these nbconvert commands:

- [[Stack Overflow Link]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67684752/jupyter-cell-tag-remove-input-has-no-effect) jupyter nbconvert --to pdf "notebook_name.ipynb"
- [[StackOverflow Link]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52834910/remove-cells-from-jupyter-notebook-with-nbconvert) jupyter nbconvert --to pdf "notebook_name.ipynb" --TagRemovePreProcessor.remove_cell_tags={"remove-cell"}

Nothing seems to work, the code continues to show every time I export or print.

The closest I have come is using the nbextension "Hide Input" but this does not persist on print or export.

Can someone please help me figure this out?  Is this just not possible?

```
jupyter --version
Selected Jupyter core packages...
IPython          : 8.4.0
ipykernel        : 6.15.0
ipywidgets       : 7.7.0
jupyter_client   : 7.3.4
jupyter_core     : 4.10.0
jupyter_server   : not installed
jupyterlab       : not installed
nbclient         : 0.6.4
nbconvert        : 6.5.0
nbformat         : 5.4.0
notebook         : 6.4.12
qtconsole        : 5.3.1
traitlets        : 5.3.0
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hiding cell in Jupyter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66110418/hiding-cell-in-jupyter)